# Cant get a JSFiddle to work

Tags: javascript, css, html, jsfiddle

I'm trying to implement a search feature using google maps and came across [this](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/2NhsE/) jsfiddle.

However, when i tried to implement it with my webpage, it fails to load the same way on the JSFiddle.

I am using the Netbeans IDE, and created an HTML5 project. This is my first html project so I am unfamilar with js/html integration.

Here is the code for the JSFiddle due to requirements

```js
function initialize() {

  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
  map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (input));

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {

    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {

      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
}
.controls {
  margin-top: 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  width: 400px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding-left: 14px;
  /* Regular padding-left + 1. */
  width: 401px;
}
.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
```

Even as I post the same code from JSFiddle into the code snippet on the site, it doesnt seem to even load.

To avoid redundency, i will only post my html file, as the CSS and JS are the same as the jsfiddle linked. (Mapper.js -> js file containing the fiddle code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<title>Google Maps with a Table</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>      

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/basecss.css">

<body>

    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Mapper.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

And finally, this is what my page looks like. Notice how the google map looks different from the JSFiddle one.

[image: My page view]

Edit - Forgot that netbeans was showing me an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SearchBox' of undefined (15:08:11:023 | error, javascript)
at initialize (public_html/js/Mapper.js:19:43)
```

> 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error suggests the google maps library did not load.

You're not rendering the google api source url from html to text.  I think your url should use `&` instead of `&amp;`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script>
```

Also missing `libraries=places` from the external resource of the jsFiddle.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: Changed that, but still got same outcome and error. Also, how does the JSFiddle load the google maps as it doesnt have any reference to the script?

Comment: On the left is an external link section.  Click on it to show libraries loaded into the project.

Comment: Ok found the problem, going to answer my question. thanks for the help

Comment: And that was the problem haha

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there was an external library loaded on the sidebar, which I did not check.

Changing this script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```